# Heroku - Python Shell Writes to File, but in Django APP View Doesn't?

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-views

I have looked and looked for this problem and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere - maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing - but I need help.

The problem:

I have created a simple 'list.txt' file that holds specific lines of code - to give example - a CSV type format. When I test the script locally it executes perfectly no issues. When I run it on Heroku on a Cedar Environment which supports temporary file writing it doesn't run as I would have thought it would.

So I test out the lines of code that run in the view in the terminal

eg.) heroku run python

The process to write to the file in shell works great, it successfully writes to the file and I can close it and reopen it and see the data I added - but it doesn't in the view.py that I have.

I have attempted to change file permissions with no luck, I've changed the folder location, no luck. I know that it recognizes the file and the location is right but it's not behaving as it would if ran in  the shell.

ex code to write in shell + view.py django.)

```
file = open(PATH_TO_FOLDER + 'list.txt', 'w')
file.write('this is a line of text')
file.close()

read_file = open(PATH_TO_FOLDER + 'list.txt', 'r')
read_file.read()
```

Any suggestions would be AMAZING!

Answer (score 1):

Disk storage on Heroku is ephemeral.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: Right! I was using system paths and that was not working. I had to store the file in the same folder as the process - works fine for now.